# Remote Desktop failed logon event 4625 not logging IP address on 2008 Terminal Services server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, terminal-server

When I use the new remote desktop with ssl and try to log on with bad credentials it logs a 4625 event as expected. The problem is, it doesn't log the ip address, so I can't block malicious logons in our firewall. The event looks like this:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /> 
        <EventID>4625</EventID> 
        <Version>0</Version> 
        <Level>0</Level> 
        <Task>12544</Task> 
        <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
        <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-04-13T06:52:36.499113600Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>467553</EventRecordID> 
        <Correlation /> 
        <Execution ProcessID="544" ThreadID="596" /> 
        <Channel>Security</Channel> 
        <Computer>ontheinternet</Computer> 
        <Security /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
        <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data> 
        <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data> 
        <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data> 
        <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
        <Data Name="TargetUserName">notauser</Data> 
        <Data Name="TargetDomainName">MYSERVER-PC</Data> 
        <Data Name="Status">0xc000006d</Data> 
        <Data Name="FailureReason">%%2313</Data> 
        <Data Name="SubStatus">0xc0000064</Data> 
        <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data> 
        <Data Name="LogonProcessName">NtLmSsp</Data> 
        <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data> 
        <Data Name="WorkstationName">MYSERVER-PC</Data> 
        <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data> 
        <Data Name="LmPackageName">-</Data> 
        <Data Name="KeyLength">0</Data> 
        <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data> 
        <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
        <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data> 
        <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

It seems because the logon type is 3 and not 10 like the old rdp sessions, the ip address and other information is not stored.

The machine I am trying to connect from is on the internet and not on the same network as the server.

Does anyone know where this information is stored (and what other events are generated with a failed logon)?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I found a way to retrieve RDP failed attempt IP address with NLA enabled (TLS/SSL)
from event log: My answer is here:
[http://serverfault.com/a/814632/385462](http://serverfault.com/a/814632/385462)

Answer (score 8):

Using TLS/SSL as encryption for the RDP protocol, Windows does not log the IP address of the user trying to log in. When you configure the server to encrypt the protocol with the (legacy) RDP encryption, it writes the IP address into the security event log.

You will have to make a trade-off. Either you will have a less secure protocol encryption or you will never know the source of a potential attack. Having the right intrusion detection system (can be downloaded for free), the system will automatically lock out the potential attacker after a defined number of invalid logins.

Read more about RDP security and intelligent intrusion detection and defense here: https://cyberarms.net/security-blog/posts/2012/june/remote-desktop-logging-of-ip-address-(security-event-log-4625).aspx

Comment: Stop spreading FUD! FYI, see my answer on how to both use SSL (i.e. confirmed server identity w/ no warnings on clients) and get Source Network Address in Event ID 4625 in the audit log.

Comment: I don't think this is true in Win10, as my honeypot is logging RDP successes and failures just fine, with IPs and with TLS enabled.

Answer (score 4):

In `secpol.msc` open `Local Policies | Security Options` set `Network security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM traffic` to `Deny all accounts`. This cannot be used with NLA but works with SSL (the SSL info icon on the topbar of `mstsc.exe` client confirms server identity) and sucessfully records source network address in failed Event ID 4625 in the audit log.

Here is my before log

```
Oct 17 13:59:22 TS04.ucssaas.local rdp-farm: {"EventTime":"2015-10-17 13:59:22","Hostname":"TS04.ucssaas.local","Keywords":-9218868437227405312,"EventType":"AUDIT_FAILURE","SeverityValue":4,"Severity":"ERROR","EventID":4625,"SourceName":"Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing","ProviderGuid":"{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}","Version":0,"Task":12544,"OpcodeValue":0,"RecordNumber":1366552,"ProcessID":568,"ThreadID":35244,"Channel":"Security","Category":"Logon","Opcode":"Info","SubjectUserSid":"S-1-0-0","SubjectUserName":"-","SubjectDomainName":"-","SubjectLogonId":"0x0","TargetUserSid":"S-1-0-0","TargetUserName":"wqw","TargetDomainName":"UCSSAAS","Status":"0xc000006d","FailureReason":"%%2313","SubStatus":"0xc000006a","LogonType":"3","LogonProcessName":"NtLmSsp ","AuthenticationPackageName":"NTLM","WorkstationName":"CVETKOV-C3414E6","TransmittedServices":"-","LmPackageName":"-","KeyLength":"0","ProcessName":"-","IpAddress":"-","IpPort":"-","EventReceivedTime":"2015-10-17 13:59:24","SourceModuleName":"eventlog","SourceModuleType":"im_msvistalog"}#015
```

and after

```
Oct 17 14:00:36 TS02.ucssaas.local rdp-farm: {"EventTime":"2015-10-17 14:00:36","Hostname":"TS02.ucssaas.local","Keywords":-9218868437227405312,"EventType":"AUDIT_FAILURE","SeverityValue":4,"Severity":"ERROR","EventID":4625,"SourceName":"Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing","ProviderGuid":"{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}","Version":0,"Task":12544,"OpcodeValue":0,"RecordNumber":2613410,"ProcessID":564,"ThreadID":17112,"Channel":"Security","Category":"Logon","Opcode":"Info","SubjectUserSid":"S-1-5-18","SubjectUserName":"TS02$","SubjectDomainName":"UCSSAAS","SubjectLogonId":"0x3e7","TargetUserSid":"S-1-0-0","TargetUserName":"wqw","TargetDomainName":"UCSSAAS","Status":"0xc000006d","FailureReason":"%%2313","SubStatus":"0xc000006a","LogonType":"10","LogonProcessName":"User32 ","AuthenticationPackageName":"Negotiate","WorkstationName":"TS02","TransmittedServices":"-","LmPackageName":"-","KeyLength":"0","ProcessName":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\winlogon.exe","IpAddress":"109.199.229.32","IpPort":"0","EventReceivedTime":"2015-10-17 14:00:37","SourceModuleName":"eventlog","SourceModuleType":"im_msvistalog"}#015
```

Basicly source `WorkstationName` is lost and now it show RDSH server name instead but you get `IpAddress` in exchange. This shows the change that happened underneath `"LogonType":"3","LogonProcessName":"NtLmSsp ","AuthenticationPackageName":"NTLM"` is changed to `"LogonType":"10","LogonProcessName":"User32 ","AuthenticationPackageName":"Negotiate"`

I'm using this setting on several Win2012 R2 session hosts and did tests with several sucessful/failed logon sessions from `mstsc.exe` clients on Win XP machines (latest `mstsc.exe` version 6.1.7600 for XP).

(The log above is from rsyslog on a haproxy load-balancer that collects audit logs from RDSH boxes that are being forwarded by nxlog service in JSON format. There is a fail2ban jail on the haproxy that blocks clients by IP after a number of failed logon attempts.)

Comment: I have installed all updates on both server (Win2k12R2) and client (Win10), but when I follow these instructions, I get the following error trying to log-on: "An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not supported
This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation.
For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660"

Comment: I'm using this setup in production in an AD domain with a separate RD connection broker server for the RD farm, not sure which one makes the difference.

Comment: @tommed you must turn of NLA

Comment: Please note that when this option is activated, the user can no longer log in with the RDP credentials stored on the the computer. The server opens a log in screen on which the user must log in manually.

Comment: @SamSirry It depends on if the user is already logged in to any other server in the RDSH farm although it's true this somehow alters standard logon behavior. A positive effect is that bots are not able to follow this somewhat weird logon sequence and brute force attacks are kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this article about log files for RDP session.
I hope it will be helpful to you.

http://forums.techarena.in/windows-security/838814.htm

I don't see one either - what is the problem specifically?

Taking a guess based on the Subject, check the Windows XP Security Event
Viewer Log. An Audit Policy may be configured using the Group Policy editor
to track logon success and failures:
From the Start | Run command window type gpedit.msc.
Navigate to Local Computer Policy | Computer Configuration | Windows
Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | Audit Policy | Audit logon
events.
Highlight and right-click and select properties.
Configure as desired.

Note that logging in without a password is logged as a failure. This results
in the security log filling up very fast if you log failures and have a user
without a password. The result is you can not login normally. Also note, not
having a password is a potential and probable security risk.

The event log can be viewed by going to Start | Control Panel | Performance
and Maintenance | Administrative Tools and click on Event Viewer.

The Event Log (Security) noting a successful logon and logoff by a remote
user. The user can highlight a log entry and right-click to view the event
Properties for detailed information.

Look in the Security Event Log for a Logon/Logoff Event 528 and Logon Type
10.

The free Microsoft Port Reporter tool provides for additional logging.
Description of the Port Reporter Parser (PR-Parser) tool
http://support.microsoft.com/default...b;en-us;884289

Availability and description of the Port Reporter tool
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837243