# why is ip address sometimes missing from Security audit log Source Network address for log on audit failures?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, ip-address, windows-event-log, audit

Most of the time when someone who is not authorized attempts to log on to my Windows 2008 R2 web server, an ip address is displayed.

With the ip address, i can easily block the external host from attempting to log on to my server by setting up a Windows firewall rule.

*usually*, the Windows Security log shows:
Logon Type:  **10**
Source Network Address:  52.24.251.116 (example is amazon.com according to ip2location.com)
Sorce Port: 6581 (varies)

example **A** , with no ip address:
Logon Type:  **10**
Workstation Name:   **my workstation name**
Source Network Address:  **0.0.0.0**
Sorce Port: **0**

example **B** , with no ip address:
Logon Type:  **3**
Workstation Name:   **CNEU-VIRTUAL**  (varies)
Account Domain:     **CNEU-VIRTUAL**  (varies)
Source Network Address:  **-**
Sorce Port: **-**

*it seems strange to me that an ip address is  missing in examples* **A** *and* **B** *above given that an* **ip address** *is essential for TCP/IP* AFAIK

according to domaintools.com, CNEU-VIRTUAL .com/.net/org have never been registered.

FWIW, i'm *guessing* that *maybe* WireShark might find an associated ip address but that, at least for me, is a lot of work ... even then, i still may not be able to get a missing ip address.

Comment: Somebody asked a similar question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/399878/security-log-in-event-viewer-does-not-store-ips

Comment: Is the server part of a domain, or is it just in a workgroup?

Comment: @LuckyLuke for all intents and purposes, it's a workgroup having only a single server, i.e., it's not dependent of AD; it's simply a win2008 R2 web server edition.

Comment: @LuckyLuke the question you mention does have some similarities however it does not seem to answer my question (although i'm still thinking it through and also following its associated sub-links).  at this point, i'm guessing that i may be forced to write some non-trivial code to locate an ip address buried in WireShark output; at the moment, my current ideas are admittedly very kludgey.  i appreciate the link. thnx