# Event Id 4625 without Source IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

We are using a total of 7 Windows Server (2008/2012) R2 Standard Editions for development and production environments. Last month our servers was compromised and we found many failed attempt logs in windows event viewer. We tried cyberarms IDDS but it didn't prove to be good earlier.

Now we have re-imaged all our servers and renamed Administrator/guest accounts. And after setting up servers again we are using [this idds](http://www.vikasrana.com/Experiment/223/ServerCloak-Intrusion-Detection-Windows-Service) to detect and block unwanted ip addresses.

The IDDS is working good but still we are getting 4625 events in event viewer without any source ip address. How can I block these requests from anonymous ip addresses ?

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
  <System>
    <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid='{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}'/>
    <EventID>4625</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12544</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-04-18T15:18:10.818780700Z'/>
    <EventRecordID>187035</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation/>
    <Execution ProcessID='24876' ThreadID='133888'/>
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>s17751123</Computer>
    <Security/>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name='SubjectUserSid'>S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name='SubjectUserName'>-</Data>
    <Data Name='SubjectDomainName'>-</Data>
    <Data Name='SubjectLogonId'>0x0</Data>
    <Data Name='TargetUserSid'>S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name='TargetUserName'>aaron</Data>
    <Data Name='TargetDomainName'>\aaron</Data>
    <Data Name='Status'>0xc000006d</Data>
    <Data Name='FailureReason'>%%2313</Data>
    <Data Name='SubStatus'>0xc0000064</Data>
    <Data Name='LogonType'>3</Data>
    <Data Name='LogonProcessName'>NtLmSsp </Data>
    <Data Name='AuthenticationPackageName'>NTLM</Data>
    <Data Name='WorkstationName'>SSAWSTS01</Data>
    <Data Name='TransmittedServices'>-</Data>
    <Data Name='LmPackageName'>-</Data>
    <Data Name='KeyLength'>0</Data>
    <Data Name='ProcessId'>0x0</Data>
    <Data Name='ProcessName'>-</Data>
    <Data Name='IpAddress'>-</Data>
    <Data Name='IpPort'>-</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**UPDATE :** 
After checking my firewall logs I think these 4625 events are not related to Rdp in anyway, but may be SSH or any other attempts which I'm not familiar with

Comment: Why do you need the ip address if you have the workstation name?

Comment: This workstation name isn't assigned to any of our server/pcs. I don't think someone can get ip address from WorkstationName?

Comment: Apparently there is/was a workstation with that name - unless the server is Internet-facing.  See this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/403638/20701

Comment: All my servers are internet-facing, so as mentioned above rdp is secured with NTLMv2. Also we are seeing ip addresses blocked after failed rdp attacks, but a few of logs in eventveiwer does not have and associated ip address. The idds we are using shows failed Rdp attacks separately than other 4625 attacks

Comment: answer is here: http://serverfault.com/a/403638/242249

Comment: This https://serverfault.com/questions/361565/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-desktop-client-and-how-can-i-trigger-a/362909#362909 and several others helped me solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 8):

IP address for failed RDP attempts is logged here even with NLA enabled (no tweaks required) (tested on Server 2012 R2, not sure about other versions)

Applications and Services Logs >
**Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational
(Event ID 140)**

Logged text example:

> A connection from the client computer with an IP address of
>   108.166.xxx.xxx failed because the user name or password is not correct.

XML:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS" Guid="{1139C61B-B549-4251-8ED3-27250A1EDEC8}" /> 
  <EventID>140</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>4</Task> 
  <Opcode>14</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-11-13T11:52:25.314996400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1683867</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{F4204608-FB58-4924-A3D9-B8A1B0870000}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="2920" ThreadID="4104" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>SERVER</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-20" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="IPString">108.166.xxx.xxx</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Thank you, and I can confirm that the same log also captures the IPs of *successful* logon events via RDP using NLA - Event ID 131.

Comment: Argh, no user name???

Answer (score 3):

This is a known limitation with the 4625 event and RDP connections using TLS/SSL.  You will need to use RDP encryption for the remote desktop server settings, or get a better IDS product.

Comment: We are already using Rdp with encryption, we have tried cyberarms and syspeace already, what else is there?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built-in Windows Firewall and its logging settings. The logs will tell you the IP addresses of all incoming connection attempts. Since you mentioned that all your servers are internet-facing, there really is **no** excuse for not using the Windows Firewall as a part of your defense in depth strategy. I would specifically recommend **not** turning off NLA (network-level authentication,) since many of the attacks on RDP in the past have historically been mitigated by the use of NLA and only affected RDP session hosts running classic RDP encryption only.

[image: Windows Firewall Logging]

Comment: The windows firewall is on with logging, the RDP is only allowed on network level authentication, so we are already doing what you have mentioned here, this is not helpful at all

Comment: The logs tell you who is connecting to port 3389 and what IP address they are coming from, 100% of the time.  You can then add that IP address to a black list in Windows Firewall.  What else do you want?

Comment: Also take a look at ts_block from @EvanAnderson: https://github.com/EvanAnderson/ts_block

Comment: After checking logs I've not found any ip on port till now which I can block, but we have ip addresses trying to access our servers on other tcp ports, like this ip: fe80::586d:5f1f:165:ac2d I found with port no 5355 . I don't think these 4625 events are generated from Rdp request, may be SSH or some other attempts.

Comment: We have now changed default ports and blocked unnecessary ports

Comment: @RyanRies - the pfirewall logs doesn't distinguish between successful and failed logins.

Comment: @Spongman No one ever said that it did. Nor did OP specify that as part of his requirement. He simply wanted a way to identify what IP addresses were establishing RDP connections to his machine when the IP doesn't appear in the Windows event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

This Event is usually caused by a stale hidden credential. Try this from the system giving the error:

From a command prompt run:    `psexec -i -s -d cmd.exe`
From the new cmd window run:  `rundll32 keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`

Remove any items that appear in the list of Stored User Names and Passwords.  Restart the computer.